# How to install Gnome 3.14 in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: gnome, 14.10

How can I install Gnome 3.14 in the new Ubuntu 14.10? I saw some guides saying that we have to add three separate repositories :

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
```

Is it necessary to add all three? Isn't gnome3-staging enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rico's PPA clearly states it depends on both the other PPAs, and the Staging PPA states it depends on the main PPA. However, looking at the current set of packages in the staging PPA for 14.10, I'd say Rico's PPA isn't needed. However, the staging PPA is not enough on its own. The main PPA is also needed.

Comment: What does the Rico's PPA have the other's doesn't? It looks like its not official right?

Comment: @EApubs It's as close to official as it gets. Rico is a prominent dev. Its the primary PPA for testing out the latest version of GNOME software on Ubuntu.